# Add object to array in JSON

Tags: json

I am trying to add an object in an array to an item in a JSON object.

The result I am looking for is:

```
{ "AvailableFacets":[ "color", "sheenlevel" ], 
  "Selections":[ 
      { "Facet":"color", "Value":"red" }, 
      { "Facet":"color", "Value":"blue" } 
  ]
}
```

but I get the error "TypeError: myJsonObject.Selection.push is not a function" when doing the following:

```
var testJson = function () {
    var myJsonObject = $.parseJSON('{"AvailableFacets":["color", "sheenlevel"]}');
    myJsonObject.Selection = "[]";
    var newObject1 = $.parseJSON('{"Facet":"color", "Value":"red"}');
    var newObject2 = $.parseJSON('{"Facet":"color", "Value":"blue"}');
    myJsonObject.Selection.push(newObject1);

    return myJsonObject;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why are you setting `Selection` to a string instead of an array?

Comment: `myJsonObject.Selection = [];`, but since you're testing JSON: `myJsonObject.Selection = $.parseJSON('[]');` :p

Comment: Am I setting it to a string? I am new to this, thought that was an array.

Comment: `"[]"` is a string containing the two characters `[` and `]`, while `[]` is an array literal containing zero items.

Comment: Got it! "[]" string, not array. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"[]"` !== `[]`. Did that help?  You are using the wrong types. Also you are looking for an output with `"Selections"` but you are attempting to define `"Selection"`, but I assume that is a typo.  This should work:

```
myJsonObject.Selection = [{"Facet":"color", "Value":"red"},{"Facet":"color", "Value":"blue"}];
```

But if you wanted to parse a string of JSON as JSON then just change

```
myJsonObject.Selection = "[]";
```

to:

```
myJsonObject.Selection = [];
```

Comment: You guys are beautiful! Both `[]` and `$.parseJSON('[]')` worked!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the typo as well, had not seen that. :)

Comment: Do I need to use `$.parseJSON` all of those times, or is it overkill?

Comment: It's overkill.  You should only use parseJSON when you are parsing a string (like from an AJAX request, or a textBox)

Comment: I kept the first $.parseJSON only, works fine without the rest.
Thank you all very much, it's wonderful to get such quick replies, especially since it's two in the morning here in Sweden :S